# udev rules doesn't work with small number

Tags: linux, udev

I was writing a udev rule that makes use of the ID_PATH, just to make the device persistent against the port it's inserted in.

So here is what I have

```
  KERNEL=="ttyUSB?",SUBSYSTEM=="tty",ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb",ENV{ID_PATH}=="pci-0000:00:12.0-usb-0:1:1.0",SYMLINK="bla"
```

Initially, the file is called 52-foo.rules, and it doesn't work. I renamed it to 81-foo.rules and it works fine.

It's like the ENV{} values are only valid if the number are large enough. Could somebody explain why this is the case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your rule is being overwritten by another rule. Since higher numbered rules run last, it doesnt get overwritten when you use a higher number.

```
< 60  most user rules; if you want to prevent an assignment being
overriden by default rules, use the := operator.

these cannot access persistent information such as that from
vol_id

< 70  rules that run helpers such as vol_id to populate the udev db

< 90  rules that run other programs (often using information in the
udev db)

>=90  rules that should run last
```

Check [this](http://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/)