# Use UUID in udev rules and mount usb drive on /media/$UUID

Tags: udev

I want to mount the usb drive in `/media` based on the UUID of the disk. How can I use the UUID of a usb drive in a udev rules file and what is a udev rule to mount the usb drive with the  UUID number as the folder name.

The `blkid` command outputs the UUID of a disk but only upon mounting.

Comment: Caveat 2019: On modern desktop Linux systems using systemd, udev rules do not mount filesystems in the regular user namespace, i.e. you cannot mount a filesystem using the mount command in a udev rule. Furthermore, in these systems, the fuse (user filesystems) system is configured to handle USB mounts via a desktop icon, so mounting by hand using an fstab rule to some degree conflicts with the fuse system. For mounting USB filesystems by UUID automatically on a headless server you would be best to remove the systemd fuse configuration and use udev rules to trigger one-shot mount services.

Comment: See this solution using fstab, systemd and automount, tested on recent Debian: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347007/31228

Answer (score 14):

Even though UUIDs are not directly accessible by udev, at least in Fedora and Ubuntu they are set as environment variables (`ENV`). You can read out all environment variables of a device by calling `udevadm info /dev/sdc`. E.g. for an NTFS on an external drive I get:

```
$ udevadm info /dev/sdc2
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc2
N: sdc2
[…]
E: ID_FS_TYPE=ntfs
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
E: ID_FS_UUID=4A6F2ABC1232FA37
[…]
```

Everything with an `E:` in front is set as an environment variable.

### Matching against UUIDs

You can match against it with `ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="4A6F2ABC1232FA37"`. As a first filter I match against `KERNEL=="sd?2"` to make sure I'm only handling block devices with the correct partition number. The complete rule would look like this:

```
KERNEL=="sd?2", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="4A6F2ABC1232FA37", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger --tag my-manual-usb-mount Mounting the device with UUID 4A6F2ABC1232FA37", RUN+="/usr/bin/mount [Your mount options here]"
```

The logger command is useful to assert that the rule is actually run. Next you should check that the rule does not contain any syntax errors with `udevadm test /dev/sdc2`. Your rules file should be listed in the output and no error message should appear next to it. Now you can trigger all rules for your device to check whether your rule works as planned: `sudo udevadm trigger /dev/sdc2`. If your rule matched you will find the custom log message in the system log (`/var/log/syslog` or via `journalctl -b`).

**Edit:** *ali_m* has pointed out that the environment variables are set by previous rules and thus only accessibly if your `.rules` file has a [sufficiently high lexicographical ordering](https://superuser.com/q/380289/215477). Starting with "60" should be enough. Personally I start my rules with "zz" (if possible) to distinguish them from predefined rules in a glance.

### Using UUIDs in the `RUN` command and elsewhere

Udev has a quite powerful variable and attribute [substitution syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15884426/371137). Specifically every occurrence of `$env{ID_FS_UUID}` will be replaced with the UUID of the drive. So to mount a device under `/media/`*`UUID`* you could use this rule:

```
KERNEL=="sd??", RUN+="/usr/bin/mkdir /media/$env{ID_FS_UUID}", RUN+="/usr/bin/mount $devpath /media/$env{ID_FS_UUID}"
```

You probably want to configure udisks instead, though, it is specialized for the problem space you want to solve. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udisks#udisks2:_mount_to_.2Fmedia as a starting point.

My actual use case for mounting devices with udev instead of `/etc/fstab` or udisks is to mount zfs file systems which have some idiosyncrasies making them not quite fit the usual tools.

Comment: One crucial point that took me a while to figure out: in order to match against environment variables, your rule must be applied *after* those variables are set up. To achieve this, [your `.rules` file name needs to begin with a number > 60](http://superuser.com/a/380431/156433).

Comment: @ali_m: Thanks, I've added your information to the answer.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, some udevadm commands can be pointed to /dev/sdXX (eg. udevadm info), others needs to be pointed to /sys/block/sdXX for some reason (eg. udevadm test).

Answer (score 0):

There's a rough solution come in my mind.
Set cooresponding fstab entry which IDed by UUID. And in udev rules, execute `mount -a` everytime there's a new sd* device added.