# simple udev rule not recognizing my drive by uuid

Tags: linux, usb-storage, udev

I am having difficulties having udev recognize a drive by uuid. I'll outline the problem with a simpler version of my problem.
If I try this simple rule (in /etc/udev/rules.d/50-backupdrive.rules):

```
ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="8eddab0f-de61-4220-bc7f-749665c40758", RUN +="/usr/bin/logger udev rule success, drive: %k with uuid $env{ID_FS_UUID}"
```

and I insert my USB drive with a partition containing that uuid, I do not see the message outputted to /var/log/syslog as expected.

However, if I run the following more generic command:

```
KERNEL=="sd?[0-9]",RUN +="/usr/bin/logger udev rule success, drive: %k with uuid $env{ID_FS_UUID}"
```

I indeed do see text outputted to /var/log:

```
Apr 22 18:06:35 xxxxxx root: udev rule success, drive: sdd2 with uuid 8eddab0f-de61-4220-bc7f-749665c40758
```

This included the uuid so indeed the uuid must be correct. Also, this confirms that udev must be working as well.

Does anyone have an idea as to what may be occurring? I have searched on these forums and not found something specific to my problem :-(. Thanks!

Some more details that may help:

Running: `udevadm info /dev/sdd2` returns ([...] means omitted text):

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdd/sdd2
N: sdd2
S: disk/by-id/ata-ST1000LM024_HN-M101MBB_S30CJ9CF767710-part2
S: disk/by-id/wwn-0x50004cf20d9dfd11-part2
S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part2
S: disk/by-uuid/8eddab0f-de61-4220-bc7f-749665c40758
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x50004cf20d9dfd11-part2 /dev/disk/by-uuid/8eddab0f-de61-4220-bc7f-749665c40758 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part2 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST1000LM024_HN-M101MBB_S30CJ9CF767710-part2
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sdd2
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/block/sdd/sdd2
E: DEVTYPE=partition
[...]
E: ID_FS_TYPE=ext4
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
E: ID_FS_UUID=8eddab0f-de61-4220-bc7f-749665c40758
```

Also, when I plug in my usb drive, `dmesg` reads:

```
[  551.257166] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[  551.257410] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdd] Spinning up disk...
[  552.260087] ..ready
[  553.264377] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdd] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  553.264382] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdd] 2048-byte physical blocks
[  553.438972] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[  553.438979] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[  553.439367] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  553.450360]  sdd: sdd1 sdd2
[  553.452429] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

Finally, `fdisk -l` gives:

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 931.5 GiB, 1000204885504 bytes, 1953525167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x709da5d9

Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1            2048  102402047  102400000  48.8G  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sdd2       102402048 1953523711 1851121664 882.7G 83 Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have your rule run *after* the built-in rule which learns the UUID in the first place.

i.e. Mine was /etc/udev.rules/30-foo.rules, but changing it to "zz-foo.rules" worked like a charm because it's guaranteed to run near the end of all rules:

```
udevadm test /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.2/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/host13/target13:0:0/13:0:0:0/block/sde/sde1
(snip)
run: '/usr/bin/logger udev rule success, drive: sde1 with uuid 456bBLAH-3399-4fec-a304-BLAH388e2bc3'
(snip)
```

Figured this out by reading
[Use UUID in udev rules and mount usb drive on /media/$UUID](https://superuser.com/questions/521402/use-uuid-in-udev-rules-and-mount-usb-drive-on-media-uuid#817797)